# Python: area of a regular polygon

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, geometry

I'm trying to calculate the area of a "regular polygon" (a regular polygon means that all sides of the polygon are the same).  I created a method to do it, however, it seems to be off by "1" and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
import math

if __name__=="__main__":

    num_sides = int(input("Enter the number of sides: "))
    side_length = float(input("Enter the side: "))

    def polygon_area(n_sides, length):
        area = (n_sides * (length ** 2)) / (4 * math.tan((math.pi) / n_sides))
        print(area)

    polygon_area(num_sides, side_length)
```

here is the formula I'm using to find the area of a regular polygon given 1 side
[image]

here is the expected output that i am supposed to get

[image]

So the expected result is supposed to be **73**.69017017488385, but I get **72**.69017017488385.  I thought it could be the order of operations or how the user input was being handled but they seem ok.  I'm not sure at this point why it's off by 1.

Comment: Check the computation by hand with a calculator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-known error in Liang's book. The right answer is *72.69017017488385*. As a side note, do not `print()` values in a function. `return` them and let the caller do the printing.

Comment: And that's why it always helps to have a professor around!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ LOL )

Comment: @user202729 Yes, it is unrelated - once you know the answer.

Comment: Thank you professor! I was going insane re-writing this function over and over in different ways lol.  I bought a digital copy of this book, not sure why they can't at least update the electronic version with the correct answer.  thank you again!